# material-ui TextField Input not working when Drawer is open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material-UI Autcomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component (Free solo version) and everything is working fine until i added resposive to the drawer `variant={!matchesSM ? 'persistent' : null}`.

```
<Drawer
  className={classes.drawer}
  variant={!matchesSM ? 'persistent' : null}
  anchor="left"
  open={sidebarOpen}
  classes={{
    paper: classes.drawerPaper,
  }}
  onClose={handleDrawerClose}
>
```

when opening the side drawer in tablet/mobile mode TextField Input is unresponsive.

here is some screenshot
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
const textFieldHandler = () => {
  handleDrawerClose();
  inputRef.current.focus();
};

 <TextField
  {...params}
  ref={inputRef}
  onClick={textFieldHandler}
  placeholder="Search input"
  margin="dense"
...
```

**Expected behavior**

On tablet/mobile mode, when opening the drawer and clicking on the textfield, drawer should be closed and textfield should be focused.

**Actual behavior**

Autocomplete is not focused in tablet & mobile when drawer is opened.

I created [this live running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-swirles-ipc1p?file=/src/App.js) to illustrate the problem:

- Text Field only works when sidebar is closed

I can't figure it out why it's not working.

Any feedback about this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Toolbar.js` you can have an `onClick` on `Textfield` and call `handleDrawerClose`

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-drawer-close-focus-issue-fix-vnh8d?file=/src/components/Topbar.js)

**Like this**

```js
<TextField
  {...params}
  onClick={handleDrawerClose}
  placeholder="Search input"
  margin="dense"
...
```

**Edit**: Based on comment.

If successfully focus on the auto complete and also open the suggestions, then we can use the Autocomplete props `openOnFocus` , `clearOnBlur`and `inputRef` prop of `Textfield`. Then in the `onClick` call `focus()` **with-in setTimeout**

```js
<Autocomplete
  openOnFocus //<---here
  clearOnBlur //<---here
  freeSolo
  id="free-solo-2-demo"
  disableClearable
  options={top100Films.map(option => option.title)}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      inputRef={ref} //<---here
      {...params}
      onClick={e => {
        handleDrawerClose(); //<---here
        setTimeout(() => ref.current.focus()); //<---here
      }}
      placeholder="Search input"
      margin="dense"
      color="secondary"
     ...
```

Comment: it helps with closing the drawer, but i can't focus the textfield once it close. i tried adding `inputRef.current.focus()` but not working. is it not possible!

Comment: all working fine now...answer has been updated ... use the same demo link (just refresh browser..)

Comment: It seems to work well with the setTimeout but I'm not feeling well with using this hack =/

Answer (score 7):

I think I've found a better solution :

thanks to this post on github : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16518#issuecomment-625218550

Adding a the "disableEnforceFocus" props to the Mui Drawer allow other inputs to be focused correctly.

```
<Drawer
  disableEnforceFocus
  {...otherProps}
>
```

Comment: You sir saved our day :thumbsup